# Windows under KVM hypervisor, constant swaping and a lot of unused RAM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, kvm-virtualization

I'm running windows server 2012 VMs with plenty of RAM assigned under Linux KVM. All 4 servers show almost 0% available memory and do a lot of swaping. The RAM used by applications doesn't add up to even half the assigned RAM. Installing RAMMAP.exe I noticed about 60% or RAM appearing as "driver locked".

What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I use `virsh edit` to set both the `CurrentMemory` and `Memory` properties of the VM to an equal amount[1] "driver locked" memory disappears, free memory appears and swaping stops!

```
 <memory unit='KiB'>3670016</memory>
 <currentMemory unit='KiB'>3670016</currentMemory>
```

---

[1] and by the way a multiple of 1024, although I don't believe this matters.